Can the three prepositions all be used with both fixed-lines and mobile phones?
I want to ask if the three prepositions can be used with both fixed-lines and mobile phones.

Calls made from/over/via fixed lines decreased.


Calls made from/over/via mobile phones increased.


They mean different things, depending on where the call originated (in the mobile phone or elsewhere). And are you interested in what's grammatical or what's most usual? And what about other prepositions (by, with, etc)? You may call yourself "newbie forever" but you've been here long enough to know how to ask a good question, including your research and being specific.

from and to obviously mean different things, but usually the former would be implied by with, over, via, by, using,... And probably other prepositions. Apart from the possible from / to distinction I can't see any scope for differences.

In the US, "landline" is the usual term, BTW.

Note that context often determines the meaning. Unless you've just lent your phone to someone, it usually wouldn't make sense to say Call me from my mobile phone. But the same preposition on can apply to either the caller or the answerer. Call me on your mobile phone and Call me on my mobile phone are both fine.

In the field of telecommunications, they'd use: fixed line calls or landline calls and mobile [tele]phone calls or cell phone calls. So, no from, over or via. https://www.conferencecalling.com/blog/the-differences-between-voip-landline-and-cell-phone-calls Also, don't forget VoIP calls.

Can you explain why you have disappeared for this question?

The from fixed lines version has just a few hits.
The over fixed lines one is similar.
The via fixed lines one has no hits.
The mobile phones version has lots of hits for its from version.
Its over version has just a few hits.
Its via version has none.
It’s hence fine to use from and over for these two channels.
Edit
My earlier search didn’t consider the fact that 'landlines' is the usual term in the UK and the US. This Ngram shows that all three prepositions are used for landline and mobile phone transmission.  It's hence fine to use all three prepositions.

That's because, as Tim R says, landline is the usual term (in the UK as well as the US). See this.

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.  I have edited my answer. I’ve used your Ngram and incorporated also data for mobile phones.

There are two things at play here: (1) How the call is transmitted; (2) The device used to place the call.
In the U.S., we call a fixed line a landline or VOIP. This describes how the call is transmitted, not the device used to make the call. It's the opposite with mobile phones. They describe the device used to place the call, not how the call is transmitted. So:
FROM

You can't call from a landline because that's the transport mechanism. You could call from a landline phone (device), but that's not very common.
You can call from a mobile phone (device).
In both cases, this refers specifically to where the call originates. It makes no assumption about the mechanism or device used to receive the call.

VIA

Via is more flexible and can usually cover both cases. You can call via landline or via mobile phone.

OVER

You can call over a landline (transport), but it would not be very common to say that.
You can't call over a mobile phone (device), but you can call over a cellular line (transport mechanism).

A call from a ship at sea to somewhere on land is called a ship-to-shore call.

landline calls or fixed-line calls
VERSUS
mobile telephone calls or cell phone calls.
No prepositions are needed.
